# C# SQL Command not ended properly

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

The following code works, however it doesn't commit the change in the database.

```
cnn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":var1", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["USERNAME"].ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":var2","1"));
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE JCOLEMAN.IBI_TEST SET FLAG=:var2 WHERE USERNAME=:var1";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cnn.Close();
```

I changed the code to the snippet below and get the error

> Additional information: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Code:

```
cnn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":var1", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["USERNAME"].ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":var2","1"));
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE JCOLEMAN.IBI_TEST SET FLAG=:var2 WHERE USERNAME=:var1; commit";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cnn.Close();
```

So I thought I forgot the last ";"(as seen below) but that causes problems, too. Can anyone help me figure out why I can't get the code to accept the commit command?

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE JCOLEMAN.IBI_TEST SET FLAG=:var2 WHERE USERNAME=:var1; commit;";
```

Comment: Have you tried using an [OleDbTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) directly instead of appending the `commit` as text? Also if this is oracle it might be better to use an Oracle specific ADO.NET db objects instead of the OleDb one which might be causing the problem.

Comment: I would use a Oracle specific ado.net library like [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), NuGet install = `Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`. This would probably better translate your commands to an appropriate Oracle platform syntax than Ole.

Comment: I thought OleDb didn't use named parameters, which means the parameters have to be in index order.  Try switching the two parameter lines around.

Comment: @LarsTech - good point. I think Ole also uses ? for parameter placeholders. Another good reason to not use it when there is a more appropriate driver available.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in Oracle you must put BEGIN END; blocks to represent a statement.

In this case you should use a transaction in your command like:

```
cnn.Open();
OleDbTransaction transaction = cnn.BeginTransaction();
OleDbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
cmd.Transaction = transaction;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":var1", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["USERNAME"].ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":var2","1"));
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE JCOLEMAN.IBI_TEST SET FLAG=:var2 WHERE USERNAME=:var1";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
transaction.Commit();
cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Do you really close the connection before committing the transaction?

Comment: I had to move the Commit() statement above the cnn.Close(); as @Henrique stated to not have any break, however the change was not committed.  I'm a step closer, I will keep looking and see what else there is.  Feel free to keep posing until I accept a full answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, you must commit before close connection.

Comment: @Henrique this worked but sadly didn't commit the changes so I am headed back to the drawing board.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Darw1n34, sorry, i've googled and I found nothing about this, All of them say that all drivers have by default autocommit. None of the comments in your question worked?

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't with the commit at all, it was with the use of the (:var2,1) line below:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":var2","1"));
```

I removed it, replaced the variable with the hard coded flag '1' and it worked like a charm!

For future reference, the code below now works in place.

```
                cnn.Open();
                OleDbTransaction transaction = cnn.BeginTransaction();
                OleDbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":var1", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["USERNAME"].ToString()));
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE JCOLEMAN.IBI_TEST SET FLAG=1 WHERE USERNAME=:var1";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                transaction.Commit();
                cnn.Close();
```

Thank you @Henrique for pushing me in the right direction.